# Iam making a Todo using (useReducer and useContext) but the update functionality is not working please check this out

Tags: reactjs, crud, react-context, use-reducer

This is my App.jsx , where iam displaying all the todos, after clicking edit the input gets the value of selected todo and while changing the value and clicking on update it does nothing.

```
export default function App() {
  const { dispatch, state } = useContext(todoContext);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [selectedTodo, setSelectedTodo] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const id = uuidv4();
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!isEditing) {
      dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TODO",
        payload: { id: id, text: todo },
      });
      setTodo("");
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: "UPDATE_TODO",
        payload: selectedTodo,
      });
      setIsEditing(false);
      setTodo("");
    }
  };

  const handleEdit = (val) => {
    setIsEditing(true);
    const item = state.todos.find((todo) => todo.id === val.id);
    setTodo(item.text);
    setSelectedTodo(item);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <br />
      <h1>Hello World This is Todo App</h1>
      <br />

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          value={todo}
          onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter a todo"
        />
        <button>{isEditing ? "Update" : "Submit"}</button>
      </form>

      {state.todos.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id} className="todoitem">
          <p
            onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_TODO", payload: item.id })}
            style={{
              cursor: "pointer",
              textDecoration: item.completed ? "line-through" : "",
            }}
          >
            {item.text}
          </p>
          <span
            onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_TODO", payload: item.id })}
          >
            &times;
          </span>
          <button onClick={() => handleEdit(item)}>Edit</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my reducers (todoReducer.jsx) , where the upadte functionality doesnot work when i click edit to  change the value and click update it does nothing

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  todos: [],
  updated: [],
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos, action.payload],
      };
    case "REMOVE_TODO": {
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload),
      };
    }
    case "TOGGLE_TODO":
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.map((todo) =>
          todo.id === action.payload
            ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed }
            : todo
        ),
      };
    case "UPDATE_TODO":
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.map((todo) => {
          if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
            return action.payload;
          }
          return todo;
        }),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I think i \ made a mistake on reducer function I don't know please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update text with latest text

- selectedTodo has old data
- todo have new text

in your **handleSubmit** please update below code

```
      dispatch({
        type: "UPDATE_TODO",
        payload: { ...selectedTodo, text: todo },
      });
```